# Inclusão de arquivos externos .js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Galera, eu tenho um arquivo .js em meudominio.com/arquivo.js (exemplo). Esse arquivo contém funções que enviam requisições via Ajax para outro arquivo, o dados.php (faz a busca e retorna em json), que se encontra na mesma pasta da hospedagem do arquivo .js. A ideia é incluir esse arquivo .js em páginas localizadas em outra hospedagem e fazer uma espécie de api.

O problema é que quando eu incluo esse .js ele acredita que o dados.php está na hospedagem do arquivo onde estou incluindo o .js, aí a requisição falha por conta disso.

Eu queria saber como enviar o post para o dados.php da hospedagem onde o .js está, e não o da hospedagem do arquivo onde estou o incluindo.

Exemplo da requisição:

```
$.ajax({
method:"post",
url:"dados.php", <= aqui eu quero que ele busque o dados.php da hospedagem onde está o .js
...
})
```

É possível fazer isso?

Comment: Deixa ver se eu entendi. Você quer fazer uma requisição POST em uma página que está fora da sua hospedagem, usando PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O nome disso é [CORS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Os navegadores e servidores, por padrão, bloqueiam qualquer requisição que não tenha vindo do servidor original. Você pode configurar seu servidor para que este possa aceitar requisições de sites que ele "conhece" ou de qualquer outro lugar.

- [Como permitir CORS no Apache](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html)
- [Como permitir CORS no NginX](http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html)

Se você não tiver acesso as configurações do servidor, você pode forçar o CORS pelo PHP, [dessa forma](http://enable-cors.org/server_php.html) (note que todas as suas páginas PHP vão precisar executar esse comando).

Answer (score 0):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` chamado de cabeçalho [CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).

Quando um site X tenta aceder o conteúdo de outro site Y, o site que fez a requisição (site X) pode enviar um cabeçalho de resposta `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` para dizer ao navegador que o conteúdo desta página está acessível a determinadas origens.
Por padrão, as páginas do site Y [não são acessíveis a outras origens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy); usando o cabeçalho `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` abre uma porta para o acesso de origem cruzada por origens solicitando específicos.

Para cada recurso/página que Site Y quer tornar acessível para o site X, o Site Y deve servir suas páginas com o cabeçalho de resposta:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://siteX.com
```

Os navegadores modernos não vao bloquear solicitações entre domínios. Se o Site X solicita uma página do Site Y, o navegador vai realmente aceder a página solicitada e verificar os cabeçalhos de resposta do Site X como um domínio solicitante permitido. Se o Site Y não indicou que o site X tem permissão para acessar esta página, o navegador irá desencadear um evento de erro no `XMLHttpRequest` e negar os dados de resposta ao código JavaScript requerente.

**Pedidos não-simples**
O que acontece ao nível da rede pode ser um pouco mais complexo do que foi explicado acima. Se o pedido é um [pedido "não-simples"](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-handling-a-not-so-simple-request), o primeiro navegador envia uma solicitação OPÇÕES "pré-impressão", para verificar que o servidor irá aceitar o pedido. Um pedido é considerado "não-simples" quando uma (ou ambas) situações:

- Usa um método HTTP diferente do GET ou POST (por exemplo, PUT,
  DELETE)
- Usa cabeçalhos de solicitação "não-simples"; os únicos pedidos
  cabeçalhos simples são:

  - `Accept`
  - `Accept-Language`
  - `Content-Language`
  - `Content-Type` (isto só é simples quando o seu valor é application /    `x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, ou `text/plain`)

Se o servidor responde às opções de comprovação com cabeçalhos de resposta adequados (`Control-Allow-Headers` para cabeçalhos "não-simples" e `Access-Access-Control-Allow-Methods` para metodos "não-simples") que correspondem ao método "não-simples" e/ou  cabeçalhos "não-simples", em seguida, o navegador envia o pedido real.

Supondo que Site X quer enviar uma solicitação PUT para `/SomePage`, com um valor `Content-Type` não-simples de `application/json`, o navegador primeiro enviar um pedido de comprovação:

```
OPTIONS /SomePage HTTP/1.1
Origin: http://siteX.com
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Access-Control-Request-Headers: Content-Type
```

Note que `Access-Control-Request-Method` e `Access-Control-Request-Headers` são adicionados pelo navegador automaticamente; você não precisa adicioná-los. Esta comprovação OPÇÕES recebe os cabeçalhos de resposta de sucesso:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://siteX.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
```

Ao enviar a solicitação real (após a comprovação ser feita), o comportamento é idêntico à forma como um simples pedido é tratado. Em outras palavras, um pedido "não-simples", cuja comprovação é bem sucedida é tratada da mesma maneira que um pedido simples (ou seja, o servidor deve ainda enviar `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` novamente para a resposta real).

O navegadores envia a solicitação real:

```
PUT /SomePage HTTP/1.1
Origin: http://siteX.com
Content-Type: application/json

{ "myRequestContent": "JSON is so great" }
```

E o servidor envia de volta um `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, da mesma forma que faria para um pedido simples:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://siteX.com
```

Veja [XMLHttpRequest Entendimento sobre CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400594/understanding-xmlhttprequest-over-cors-responsetext/13400954#13400954) para um pouco mais de informação sobre os pedidos não-simples.

Fonte: [apsillers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10636765/3419602)